# Changing the color of theorem headings

Tags: color, theorems, amsthm

I have a theorem environment, and I would like:

- The text color of `Problem`s and their contents to be a custom color (defined as `db' below)
- The text color of `Solution`s to be a custom color (defined as `dg' below), **BUT NOT** it's contents. I would like the contents to remain black.
- I would not like the contents of `Problem`s and `Solutions`s to be italicized
- Keep the same counter

  ```
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsthm}

  \definecolor{db}{RGB}{23,20,119}
  \definecolor{dg}{RGB}{2,101,15}

  \newtheoremstyle{dotless}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{}{ }{}
  \theoremstyle{dotless}
  %\theoremstyle{plain}% default
  \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}%[section]
  \newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
  \newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
  \newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
  \newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
  \newtheorem{examp}[thm]{Example}
  \newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
  \newtheorem{rmk}[thm]{Remark}
  \newtheorem{prob}[thm]{Problem}
  \newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}
  \newtheorem*{qu}{Question}
  \newtheorem*{as}{Assumptions}
  \newtheorem*{rs}{Restatement}
  \newtheorem*{ques}{Question}
  ```

I've found a few pages about relevant information, but most of it was regarding boxing theorems or changing the entire environment.

Comment: From the many-argumented `\newtheoremstyle`, I assume you use `amsthm`?

Comment: Are you referring to a background color or you just want the text to receive some color?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Yes, amsthm, my apologies. I have added the package to the code.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The actual color of the text. For `Problem`s I would like the word and count of problem to have the text color, as well as the contents. For `Solution`, I would like it to have the text color green, **but** I would like its contents to remain black. I have updated the question to be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would imagine the following is sufficient. That is, define a `\newtheoremstyle` for the `prob` and `sol` theorems each:

```
\newtheoremstyle{dotlessP}{}{}{\color{db}}{}{\color{db}\bfseries}{}{ }{}
\theoremstyle{dotlessP}
\newtheorem{prob}[thm]{Problem}
\newtheoremstyle{dotlessS}{}{}{}{}{\color{dg}\bfseries}{}{ }{}
\theoremstyle{dotlessS}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!!! I didn't realize I could change the theorem style while keeping them in the same families.

Comment: How can I change the color of the heading only, in **theorems**,**lemmas**, **definitions** etc, to the red color. many thanks

Comment: @user35528: It depends on how they are defined, since different packages provide different interfaces.