# Colouring theorem environment

Tags: color, environments

I would like to change the theorem environment so that the title and name are coloured.  What can I do?  Have checked ways to do this (e.g. with `\newtheoremstyle`) but have not worked well yet.  I do not want to use theorom packages such as `amsthm`, but stick with basic built-in theorem structure.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[b5paper,body={13cm,18cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}  

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Continuous Function]
  Let \(f\) be a function whose derivative exists in every point,
  then \(f\) is a continuous function.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

I would have other environments using `\newtheorem` that I would want the same colouring scheme as would happen with `\begin{theorem}` ... `\end{theorem}`.

Comment: Can you add a minimal working example so we can see which of the theorem packages you are using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the color of theorem headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155516/changing-the-color-of-theorem-headings)

Comment: I could not get that one to work for me.

Comment: That example does not even compile. You still need to define `theorem`. This should be diable using `thmtools` (haven't tested it) or directly via `amsthm` and defining custom theorem styles.

Comment: I want to use the built-in latex functionality to do it without `amsthm`.  Doable but how?

Comment: If you ask someone a direct question please use `@name` to notify. `thmtools` works with regular `\newtheorem`. What is wrong with using `amsthm`? You're already using `xcolor` so what is the point is requiring build-in latex functionality?

Comment: I'm voting to leave open because the OP asks for a solution without `amsthm`, which makes it a different question.

Comment: @konmi -- If you don't want to use `amsthm` or other particular packages, please add that to your question.

Comment: There isn't any such thing as "basic builtin theorem structure" as far as I know. Your current code does not compile because no theorem environment is defined. Why don't you want to use amsthm? How are you defining theorem environments now?

Comment: @frabjous do remember that `\newtheorem ` is in the core. The op does not need amsthm, it is just a strange requirement to not use packages

Comment: Here is where we disagree. I only want to change colour for something that is in core without relying on theorem packages.

Answer (score 1):

In https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17555/4427 you find the default values for theorem styles. You just need to tailor the last argument to your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtheoremstyle{colorplain}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {%
   \thmnumber{\textcolor{red!75}{#1}}%
   \ % space
   \thmname{\textcolor{green!60!red}{#2}}%
   \thmnote{ \textcolor{blue!80!green}{#3}}%
  }

\theoremstyle{colorplain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This has no theorem note.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Note]
This has a theorem note.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But this is definitely ugly. I believe you just want one color for the whole heading.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtheoremstyle{colorplain}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\color{blue!80!green}\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}

\theoremstyle{colorplain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This has no theorem note.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Note]
This has a theorem note.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Albeit using both the `amsthm` and `thmtools` environments, something like this?

(I also corrected the run-on sentence and corrected the preposition "in" to be "at.")

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[b5paper,body={13cm,18cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont={\color{red}\bfseries},
  notefont={\color{blue}},
]{thmstyle}
%
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=thmstyle]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Continuous Function]
  If \(f\) is a function whose derivative exists at every point,
  then \(f\) is a continuous function.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: Color theorem head and note]